# Unable to create a Android project in Android Studio (I/0 Preview) 130.737825 (Mac)

Tags: android, android-studio

I opened my Android Studio today and it asked to upgrade to the latest version which I did.

Now I am unable to create a new project. I follow the wizard to create a project and it finishes with creating the project, but the result is not what I expected and I get a error in the console

The error I get is:

```
Can't deserialize target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given class loaders: [PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]: Can't deserialize target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given class loaders: [PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't deserialize target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given class loaders: [PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.DataNode.prepareData(DataNode.java:159)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.ensureTheDataIsReadyToUse(ProjectDataManager.java:110)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.wizard.AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder$1$1$1.run(AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder.java:140)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.mergeRootsChangesDuring(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:314)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.wizard.AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder$1$1.run(AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$6$1.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:323)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1002)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$6.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2003)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:340)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:318)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:314)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.wizard.AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder$1.run(AbstractExternalProjectImportBuilder.java:134)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$7.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:286)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivities(StartupManagerImpl.java:259)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$100(StartupManagerImpl.java:52)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$4.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.runWhenSmart(DumbServiceImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runPostStartupActivities(StartupManagerImpl.java:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl$4$2.run(ProjectManagerImpl.java:439)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:686)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:514)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:339)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.ArtifactInfoImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8019119530161366598, local class serialVersionUID = 4262527033625760143
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:570)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:979)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:478)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.readObject(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:979)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.DataNode.prepareData(DataNode.java:155)
    ... 37 more
```

When I try to import it does the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

I must ask you for your Android Studio Build number and your system environment. But I think the following step may help. And sorry for poor English if there is any spell mistake.

Under Windows 7 x64
Android Studio 130.737825

First,check your Android Studio version . I have the problem when the version is 130.737825  . Anyway update Android Studio.  "Help->Check for Update"

if it didn't work.

http://tools.android.com/recent

to check the newest Build Number or

http://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/updates.xml

check the newest version .

Download Update package
like this one https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/AI-130.737825-132.821530-patch-win.jar
Please according to your own situation choose to down the right one. The format is AI-$FROM-$TO-patch-win.jar  $From is the build number your Android studio.  $TO is the newest build number you want to update.

Download the package to your Android Studio directory. D:\Android\android-studio.
Run cmd

```
D:\Android\android-studio>java -classpath AI-130.737825-132.821530-patch-win.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install .
```

Comment: It may be the bug with Android studio build 130.737825

Comment: Updating fixed this for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Moving my projects to the same partition as my Android Studio seems to have solved my problem.
Not a permanent solution but if you want to continue with your work before they fix it, you've got to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I have this error, is your user folder located on a drive other than where android studio is installed?

I would've put this as a comment but can't.

Comment: I only have 1 partition so this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As shell said:

```
WARNING: You are launching the IDE using OpenJDK Java runtime.

         ITS KNOWN TO HAVE PERFORMANCE AND GRAPHICS ISSUES!
         SWITCH TO THE ORACLE(SUN) JDK BEFORE REPORTING PROBLEMS!

NOTE:    If you have both Oracle (Sun) JDK and OpenJDK installed
         please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME, or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid Oracle (Sun) JDK installation.
         See http://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installation-guide.html?section=Windows#h2linux for more info on switching default JDK.
```

I think this is the problem. You must switch android-studio's jdk to the right path.

Comment: It also warns me about this on Ubuntu, but it still works fine.

Comment: I tried several things: adding STUDIO_JDK which points to /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home or /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home (tried both), changing project structure in Studio and pointing to JDK 1.7 of JDK 1.6. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Win7-x64. I had put path to jdk (c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40) for JAVA_HOME (goto Control Panel->System->Environment Variable) in double quotes. Removing the quotes fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64, updating (to v. 0.3.1 at the time of this writing) also fixed the problem.
To update, as some already listed, just click on "Help -> Check for Update".