# I update to android studio 1.5 but I got error android.builder.model.AndroidProject PluginClassLoader

Tags: java, android, android-studio

all I did just update to android studio 1.5 I got this error

any one can guide me why this error happen and how can I fix it

```
Error:com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.1.4.1]
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803858/unable-to-create-a-android-project-in-android-studio-i-0-preview-130-737825-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all I do just completely close android studio android open it again